# Find the indices of the two largest and not consecutive values

Tags: python, sorting, max

Given the following vector,

```
a = [0, 11, 22, 10, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 23, 25, 18, 10]
```

I need to identify the indices of "a" whose elements are the two largest not consecutive values like this:

```
idx = [2, 10]
```

(a[2] = 22; a[10] = 25).

Moreover it will be possible to set a minimum distance gap (my_gap) between these finding numbers; for example in the followin vector,

```
a = [10, 11, 14, 28, 10, 30, 8, 11, 13, 11, 28, 10]
```

I would like to have: `idx= [5, 10]` because I want a gap in positions between the largest values of at least 3. In the example the first '28' is too close the the '30' (they differ of 5-2=3 positions, the other '28' is farther from the '30' -->abs(5-10) = 5 > my_gap).

To be more precise and avoid misunderstandings is there any pythonic way to rewrite the following code?
Thanks

```
import numpy as np

a = [60, 2, 3, 21, 18, 22, 0, 70, 118, 111, 100, 120, 10, 6]
idx = np.argsort(a)[::-1]
a_sorted = np.sort(a)[::-1]
n_gap = 3

first_value = a_sorted[0]
second_value = []
for i in range(1, len(idx)):
    if abs(idx[0] - idx[i]) > n_gap:
        second_value = a_sorted[i]
        break
print('first value: ', first_value)
print('second value: ', second_value)
```

Comment: What does it mean for largest values? Is it the largest sum, product, etc? It's unclear how you define largest on two values.

Comment: @MLavrentyev I mean in absolute value, e.g. in the vector a = [10, 11, 100, 3, 4, 120] the two largest values are: 120 and 100.

Comment: what if you have [20, 21, 19, 18]? What are the largest numbers? 20,19 or 21, 18?

Comment: @LucaR What's the expected behavior in this input? `[10, 8, 9, 11]` - is it 0, 2 (10 and 9) or 1, 3 (11 and 8)

Comment: @MLavrentyev  (@Riccardo Buco) : In the example that you have reported I would prefer that the expected behavior is 1, 3  (11>10). I just want to point out that in my pratical case I have a sparse vector more like a = [0, 0, 0, 10, 15, 16, 15, 0, 0, 0, 11,13,15,12,10]. So I would expect the output: idx = [5, 12] that corresponds to the numbers: 16 and 15 (the one no close to the 16)

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this with the `max()` and `index()` function.
First, get the index and the value of the max value from the list, then drop the required values from my_gap with `remove()` and then do another `max()` search again. Something likes this:

```
max_value = a.max()
max_index = a.index(max_value)
my_gap = 5

for i,j in enumerate(a):
  if i > max_index - my_gap and i < max_index + my_gap:
     a.remove(i)

max_value2 = a.max()
max_index2 = a.index(max_value)
```

Keep in mind that it would be better to create a copy of the list before removing things.

Answer (score 0):

Linear complexity version.
Roughly O(N) time and constant space

It works by building a list of the maximum values up to each index,
and then checking each element and the maximum value up to (current element's index - k),
This works because the maximum value up to (this index - k) will be the optimal pairing for the current element, and maximum pairs must contain the maximum value of the list.

```py
a = ([0, 11, 22, 10, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 23, 25, 18, 10],
     [10, 11, 14, 28, 10, 30, 8, 11, 13, 11, 28, 10],
     [20, 21, 19, 18, 17],
     [10,8,9,11,12],
     [0, 0, 0, 10, 15, 16, 15, 0, 0, 0, 11,13,15,12,10],
     [60, 2, 3, 21, 18, 22, 0, 70, 118, 111, 100, 120, 10, 6])

n_gap = 3 #minimum distance

k = n_gap + 1 # k is position offset, which is 1 more than gap size
for a in a:
    if(len(a) <= k): # not enough elements for gap size
        print('no answer')
        continue
    m = a[0]
    mi = 0
    maxes = (m, a[k], mi, k)
    for i,x in enumerate(a):
        if x > m:                         #new maximum found
            if i >= k:                      #index big enough to have a pair
                mit, mt = a[i - k]             #get incremental maximum at gap
                maxes = (x, mt, i, mit)     #init maxes with max pair candidate
            mi, m = i, x                  #track new maximum
        else:
            if i - mi >= k:                    #gap from last maximum big enough
                mit, mt = a[i - k]               #get incremental maximum at gap
                maxes = max(maxes,(mt, x, mit, i))  #check max pair candidate
        a[i] = (mi, m) # fill [a] with incremental maximums

    print(maxes) #find maximum pair candidate
```